# Contains invalid quaternions (length not equal to 1)!

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
When i use RVIZ to read the vector_map data.
The status is error. it show that "Contains invalid quaternions (length not equal to 1)!"
would you help me to find something wrong?
my system:
ubuntu 16.04
ros kinetic

thanks

Frank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278621/contains-invalid-quaternions-(length-not-equal-to-1)!/) by [Franklin4080](https://answers.ros.org/users/33124/franklin4080/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2018-01-03**:
Hi @Franklin4080.
Please, be more specific: how did you generate the "vector_map"?
If you created the node that generates the "vector_map", did you remember to normalize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also recently ran into this exact same error message when trying to visualize a nav_msgs/Path topic with invalid (all zeros) quaternions in the path poses. Our code doesn't use the orientation portion of the pose and we had been able to visualize these paths with no problems before. I have version 1.12.14 of rviz and my colleague who had version 1.12.13 of rviz was able to visualize our paths.

TLDR: It seems like the latest version of rviz (1.12.14) is more strict about quaternions according to the [changelog](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/blob/1.12.14/CHANGELOG.rst#11214-2017-12-19)

---

Originally posted by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) with karma: 253 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-04**:
See also [ros-visualization/rviz#1176](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1176). [ros-visualization/rviz#1179](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1179) is a follow-up with some discussion.